# Extract data from dataframe based on variable as per user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can i extract data from dataframe as per the user input or default value set by function. i'm trying it for too long

current user input is working fine only problem is its not extracting data from dataframe739987

```
data = {
  "Brand": ['ABC','XYZ'],
  "Category": ['GKK','KKL','MKK','UKK']
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
Final_Datanew = pd.DataFrame(data)

#code for user input & function if userinput is blank then set default value
def split_or_default(prompt, default):
    response = input(prompt + " (" + "/".join(default) + ") ")
    if response == "":
        return default
    return response.split(",")

Brand = split_or_default(
    'Please enter Brand?',
    ['ABC','XYZ'])
Cate = split_or_default(
    'Please enter Category?',
    ['GKK','KKL','MKK','UKK'])

#filtering userinput in dataframe
Final_Datanew.loc[(Final_Datanew['Brand'].isin(Brand)) & (Final_Datanew['Category'].isin(Cate)) ]
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, can you describe how this fails?

Comment: not getting any rows in the output @mozway

Comment: Please be specific. I tested ABC / GKK and ABC / nothing and get the matching rows. Don't you? Maybe you wanted OR rather than AND?

Comment: ``` Please enter Brand? (ABC/XYZ) BMW
Please enter Category? (GKK/KKL/MKK/UKK) 
output:Brand Category
```

Comment: Well, `BMW` is not in any row, so it's expected to have 0 rows in the output, no?